# Speech Recognizer online in Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have big problem with speech recognition in Windows Phone 8.1 application.
My code (I found something like this in Google):

```
private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;

public async Task InitializeSpeechRecognizerAsync()
{
    speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

    SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint topicConstraint =
        new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.Dictation,
        "dictation");

    speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(topicConstraint);

    await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
}
```

And click event:

```
private async void BtnAge_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SpeechRecognitionResult recognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
}
```

Of course - it doesn't work and throws exception

```
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

I know how to recognize speech on Windows Phone 8.0, but have no idea how to do it on WP 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device has a suitable speech language installed and associated with the Recognizer object. You can verify with the language-related properties as [documented on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognizer.aspx)

Comment: Language in appxmanifest is "en-us", in device is "en-us" and I added parameter in
speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(new Windows.Globalization.Language("en-us"));
but it didn't help - still the same error

Comment: Did you wait for the compilation to succeed?

Comment: Do you have network access and the internetClient capability?

Comment: Yes. Offline (with data from the list) everything works. But I need to recognize cities

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the code to initialize the recognizer in the same method where you call RecognizeWithUIAsync().
Here is a code from my own application that definitely works:

```
public async Task<string> RecognizeSpeech()
{
  SpeechRecognizer recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
  SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint topicConstraint = new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.Dictation, "Message");
  recognizer.Constraints.Add(topicConstraint);
  await recognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
  SpeechRecognitionResult result = await recognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
  if (result.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.High || result.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.Medium)
  {
    return result.Text;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why this doesn't work in my application. I still have an error 
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
in third line